# How to change ContentPresenter Color WPF

Tags: wpf, expression-blend

I have a custom button in WPF. On disabled state I want it's content color to change, but I can't manage to do that. I'm using Blend for Visual Studio. When I go to edit template and choose contentPresente's brush color it says that value is invalid. How can I do that ? I tried to change it in XAML and this is the code I used but there is an error.

```
<ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="contentPresenter">
    <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Black" />
</ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[ContentPresenter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentpresenter.aspx) by itself does not have any Visual `Style`'s. It's merely a placeholder for the `Content` of the `Control` in the `Style` which it resides in.

To modify the `Foreground` in your custom `Button`'s `Style.ControlTemplate`, you could use the attached property `TextElement.Foreground` on the `ContentPresenter` with a `Trigger` for `IsEnabled="False"`

```
...
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
  ...
  <Trigger Property="IsEnabled"
            Value="False">
    <Setter TargetName="contentPresenter"
            Property="TextElement.Foreground"
            Value="Red" />
  </Trigger>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
...
```

You can accordingly do the same via `Storyboard`'s or the `VisualStateManager` via blend for the same property.

**Note:**

Very important to understand that by doing this^^ we are assuming the `Button` using this `Style` to have its `Content` as some Text. If your `Button.Content` is something else like another `FrameworkElement`(say a `ComboBox`) You will not see it become "Red".

Comment: Is there a way to do it for any element, like `Image` ?

Answer (score 1):

Found a "Hacky" way to do this for any element by using `ControlTemplate.Resources` and `TargetType`:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="GlyphButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
  <ControlTemplate.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type fa:ImageAwesome}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gray"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Button}}}" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF048758"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </ControlTemplate.Resources>
  <ContentPresenter/>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Sadly you can't use button's `VisualStateManager` this way.

Comment: Great trick! This even works if the control template's ContentPresenter just represents another content presenter (i.e. using a ContentSource tag) in a nested template setup; in this case the property for the setter would be "TextElement.Foreground"...